# Select first child element with specific class

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've done some searching and I can't find a straight forward answer to this pretty simple question.

I have a bunch of containers like so that repeat:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text">asd</div>
    <div class="text2">asd</div>
    <div class="text3">asd</div>
</div>

<div class="hidden_container" style="display:none;">hidden text</div>
```

So far, when you click on `.container` it shows the `.hidden_container` with the following code:

```
$(".container").click(function() {
    $(this).next(".hidden_container").toggle();
    return false;   
});
```

What I am trying to do is select `.text2` on click as well and add a class to it. But I am having trouble selecting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following

```
$($(this).find(".text2")[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(".container").click(function() {
   var sel = $(this).find('.text2');
   sel.addClass('someclass');
    $(this).next(".hidden_container").toggle();
    return false;   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

cleaner way of doing it:

```
$(this).find('.text2:first');
```